# How to correctly serialize Javascript curried arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, serialization, closures, currying, arrow-functions

```
const makeIncrementer = s=>a=>a+s
makeIncrementer(10).toString()    // Prints 'a=>a+s'
```

which would make it impossible to de-serialize correctly (I would expect something like `a=>a+10` instead.
Is there a way to do it right?

Comment: i think there is no way

Comment: Why would you expect `a=>a+10`? You are calling `makeIncrementer(10)` which is returning a function `a=>a+s` and when you `toString()` it, it returns the function body

Comment: @JohanP, No, `makeIncrementer(10)` returns the function `a=>a+s` with `s` bound to value `10`, so, technically, the function `a=>a+10`. I just want to find a way to extract the bound value of `s` from the returned function object.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, I agree that the value is bound, my question is why would you expect calling `toString()` on a function to spill its internal/bound values?

Comment: @JohanP, I am just trying to find a way to extract it *somehow*. To be perfectly precise, I need to write `serialize` and `restore` routines such that: `str = serialize((s=>a=>a+s)(10)) && typeof(str) === 'string' && restore(str)(5) === 15`. Hope, I'm clear enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining ideas from the two answers so far, I managed to produce something that works (though I haven't tested it thoroughly):

```
const removeParentheses = s => {
    let match = /^\((.*)\)$/.exec(s.trim());
    return match ? match[1] : s;
}

function serializable(fn, boundArgs = {}) {
    if (typeof fn !== 'function') return fn;
    if (fn.toJSON !== undefined) return fn;

    const definition = fn.toString();
    const argNames = removeParentheses(definition.split('=>', 1)[0]).split(',').map(s => s.trim());

    let wrapper = (...args) => {
        const r = fn(...args);

        if (typeof r === "function") {
            let boundArgsFor_r = Object.assign({}, boundArgs);
            argNames.forEach((name, i) => {
                boundArgsFor_r[name] = serializable(args[i]);
            });
            return serializable(r, boundArgsFor_r);
        }
        return r;
    }

    wrapper.toJSON = function () {
        return { function: { body: definition, bound: boundArgs } };
    }
    return wrapper;
}

const add = m => m1 => n => m + n * m1,
    fn = serializable(add)(10)(20);

let ser1, ser2;

console.log(
    ser1 = JSON.stringify(fn)          // {"function":{"body":"n => m + n * m1","bound":{"m":10,"m1":20}}}
);

const map = fn => xs => xs.map(fn),
    g = serializable(map)(n => n + 1);

console.log(
    ser2 = JSON.stringify(g)   // {"function":{"body":"xs => xs.map(fn)","bound":{"fn":{"function":{"body":"n => n + 1","bound":{}}}}}}
);

const reviver = (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && 'function' in value) {
        const f = value.function;
        return eval(`({${Object.keys(f.bound).join(',')}}) => (${f.body})`)(f.bound);
    }
    return value;
}

const rev1 = JSON.parse(ser1, reviver);
console.log(rev1(5));   // 110

const rev2 = JSON.parse(ser2, reviver);
console.log(rev2([1, 2, 3]));   // [2, 3, 4]
```

This works for arrow functions, that do not have default initializers for the arguments. It supports higher order functions as well.
One still has to be able to wrap the original function into `serializable` **before** applying it to any arguments though.
Thank you @MattWay and @ftor for valuable input !

Answer (score 4):

This is a great question. While I don't have a perfect answer, one way you could get details about the argument/s is to create a builder function that stores the necessary details for you. Unfortunately I can't figure out a way to know which internal variables relate to which values. If I figure out anything else i'll update:

```js
const makeIncrementer = s => a => a + s
const builder = (fn, ...args) => {
  return {
    args,
    curry: fn(...args)
  }  
}
var inc = builder(makeIncrementer, 10)
console.log(inc) // logs args and function details
console.log(inc.curry(5)) // 15
```

---

UPDATE: It will be a mammoth task, but I realised, that if you expand on the builder idea above, you could write/use a function string parser, that could take the given args, and the outer function, and rewrite the log to a serialised version. I have a demo below, **but it will not work in real use cases!**. I have done a simple string find/replace, while you will need to use an actual function parser to replace correctly. This is just an example of how you could do it. *Note that I also used two incrementer variables just to show how to do multiples.*

```js
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace)
}

const makeIncrementer = (a, b) => c => c + a + b
const builder = (fn, ...args) => {
  // get the outer function argument list
  var outers = fn.toString().split('=>')[0]
  // remove potential brackets and spaces
  outers = outers.replace(/\(|\)/g,'').split(',').map(i => i.trim())
  // relate the args to the values
  var relations = outers.map((name, i) => ({ name, value: args[i] }))
  // create the curry
  var curry = fn(...args)
  // attempt to replace the string rep variables with their true values
  // NOTE: **this is a simplistic example and will break easily**
  var serialised = curry.toString()
  relations.forEach(r => serialised = replaceAll(serialised, r.name, r.value))
  return {
    relations,
    serialised,
    curry: fn(...args)
  }  
}
var inc = builder(makeIncrementer, 10, 5)
console.log(inc) // shows args, serialised function, and curry
console.log(inc.curry(4)) // 19
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I actually HAVE already developed the "mammoth" machinery needed to parse the JS expressions: please, take a look at https://github.com/dmaevsky/rd-parse/tree/master/examples/jsexpr. I just find it quite unfortunate that there's no way to extract the curried parameters directly from the function object returned by `makeIncrementer(10)` in my example

Comment: Yeah, the question is really, can you access the details of a `bind()`? Unfortunately it looks like you cannot, which is a shame.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't serialize/parse function bodies since this quickly leads to security vulnerabilities. Serializing a closure means to serialize its local state, that is you have to make the closure's free variables visible for the surrounding scope:

```js
const RetrieveArgs = Symbol();

const metaApply = f => x => {
  const r = f(x);

  if (typeof r === "function") {
    if (f[RetrieveArgs])
      r[RetrieveArgs] = Object.assign({}, f[RetrieveArgs], {x});
  
    else r[RetrieveArgs] = {x};
  }

  return r;
}

const add = m => n => m + n,
  f = metaApply(add) (10);

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(f[RetrieveArgs]) // {"x":10}
);

const map = f => xs => xs.map(f)
  g = metaApply(map) (n => n + 1);

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(g[RetrieveArgs]) // doesn't work with higher order functions
);
```

I use a `Symbol` in order that the new property doesn't interfere with other parts of your program.

As mentioned in the code you still cannot serialize higher order functions.

Comment: Oh, I like it !. Actually, you *can* serialize higher order functions this way too. It is just that in your example `JSON.stringify` ignores functions. But with a proper replacer (which would be the function serialization function itself that we are trying to cook here), it would work the same way. In your example adding `const replacer = (key, value) => typeof(value) === 'function'? value.toString() : value` prints `{"x":"n => n + 1"}`

Comment: However, you still need to wrap the original function with metaApply, *before* applying it to an argument, similar to the `builder` in @MattWay 's answer, which is not feasible in all contexts. I guess the closure bound parameters are kept private by design :/

Comment: But if you serialize functions the way you describe, you'd have to use `eval`/`Function` at some point, right? Anyway, this is an interesting question, because as a functional programmer I treat functions as data by building structures of partially applied functions (aka closures). However, serializing these structures doesn't come for free, but seems to be pretty hard.

Comment: I transformed a little your idea and posted it as a new answer. In order to de-serialize the output, you could indeed use eval, or a proper ES6 expression parser. Fortunately, I already have one: https://github.com/dmaevsky/rd-parse/tree/master/src/examples/jsexpr

Comment: @Dmitry A parser generator and a ES6 expression grammar, impressive! Now your question makes a lot more sense. It would be interesting to implement this grammar as parser combinators based on bennu or parsimmon.