# can't pass bound/curried/closure functions from node to browser with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I was recently playing with node and puppeteer.

I am facing the issue that if I need to partially apply a function I can't pass it to the the browser because it needs to be serialized, problem is that the arguments bound are lost in the process.

This is something similar to my issue but this only works for very specific case of arrow functions.
[How to correctly serialize Javascript curried arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49743848/how-to-correctly-serialize-javascript-curried-arrow-functions)

EDIT: it works for normal functions as well as pointed in the comment. but trying to serialize a already bound function did not work.

Anybody knows how to get around this problem? What I have been doing is loading a object with the arguments and passing it all with an array of functions with the order.

Comment: "*this only works for very specific case of arrow functions*" - I don't think so.

Comment: You are right, the actual problem was when I bind it, it works if I pass all args, but if use a already bound function it gives output but not the correct. I am editing it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, bound functions cannot be serialised because you cannot access their internals. You'll need to take the same approach as with the other closures: explicitly create a serialisable object instead of binding it. You can achieve that by overwriting the `.bind` method if you need to.

Comment: Right, now that you mention it. It does make sense.

I think the way here is to stick with the wrapper to collect the args and functions to run in the browser. Sort of a modified cross env curry + compose.

Thanks for your inputs.